# Can d3.format ignore trailing 0s?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to use d3.format() on a real number so that I can have all the significant digits up to but not including any remaining zeroes.

Basically, I'm looking for `X` such that:

```
// with floating-point precision 1
var f = d3.format(X);

f(11.304) -> 11.3
f(5.2) -> 5.2
f(1) -> 1
f(1.01) -> 1
f(1.00) -> 1
f(0.004) -> 0
```

So far, I've [tried](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format) using variations of `.1f`, `.1g` & `.1r`, to no avail.

Would I need to manually check and truncate the result of the formatted number to get what I need?

I am using d3.js v3.3.1.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to do the check manually.

Comment: Try something like `d3.format(',.1f')`. It works as expected on my charts.

Comment: Do you also use nvd3?

Comment: @Florent thanks for your response. I don't use nv.d3.js, but from the source code, it seems they use vanilla d3.format(). the ',' is just a thousands separator. are you doing anything else to have your formatting ignore trailing 0s?

Comment: No I don't. Maybe you are using a buggy version of d3...